# Jacobian of Van der Pol system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, jacobian

I am trying to figure out how to find the jacobian of the following:

$$du/dt = w$$
$$dw/dt=B(1-u^2)w-u$$

I think the jacobian would be: (Let d be a partial for ease)
\begin{bmatrix}
du/dt \\
dw/dt \\
\end{bmatrix}

But I feel like I am missing a column but I can't figure out what it would be :/
Would it be wrt u maybe?

Comment: What do you mean by "Jacobian of a system"? The $m\times n$ Jacobian matrix (determinant) is defined for a map $f\colon\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ with $a_{ij}=\dfrac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}$ where $f_i$ is the restriction of $f$ to the $i^{\textrm{th}}$ component.

Comment: Do you mean the Jacobian of $f(t):=(u(t),w(t))$ which is a map $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$ ? In that case, your attempt is correct (you aren't missing a column, it _should_ be a $2\times 1$ matrix).

Comment: Maybe that is why I am confused. I made the van der pol equation of $u''=-u+B(1-u^2)u'$ into the system above but I am trying to find the "jacobian of the system" Is how it is worded on the question...

Comment: The Jacobian is a $n\times n$ square matrix only for $f\in\operatorname{End}_\Bbb R(\Bbb R^n)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$du/dt = w=f(u,w)$$
$$dw/dt=B(1-u^2)w-u=g(u,w)$$
The Jacobian matrix is the matrix of the  linearized system

$$ \begin {bmatrix} f_u&f_w\\g_u&g_w\end {bmatrix}=  \begin {bmatrix} 0&1\\-2Buw-1&B(1-u^2)\end {bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks for your attention.